# What's the meaning 'EEE'

Tags: angularjs, date

Looking at date filter on angular.js, `EEE` is used on the spot of the day of the week part, What's the meaning `EEE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EEE` term is used to custom format `Datetime` `String`:

```
'EEEE': Day in Week,(Sunday-Saturday)
'EEE': Day in Week, (Sun-Sat)
```

reference -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

**Usage**

In HTML Template Binding:

```
  {{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

In JavaScript:

```
  $filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

Comment: `M` is the first letter of month. `m` is the first letter of minute. I'm curious about `EEE`.

Comment: `'M': Month in year (1-12)` and ` 'mm': Minute in hour, padded (00-59)`
 
`'m': Minute in hour (0-59)`

Comment: Why developers (of angularjs) uses `EEE`?

Comment: That's really not a angular thing, is more a convention on string format for dates. You can see the same pattern in java data https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I think it is second letter of week. right? I'm not sure.

Comment: what do you mean? No dude you can use just like `$filter('date')(new Date(), "EEE")` the output would be -> `Mon`

Comment: This format string, which means the day of the week, why not use the `WWW` wondered whether `EEE`.

Answer (score 0):

From: [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

`'EEE': Day in Week, (Sun-Sat)`

That is, providing a formatter of 'EEE' will convert the date object to expose only the day in the week (like `Sunday`).